# consolidate columns that may or may not have overlapping data, using R

Tags: r, merge, cbind, consolidation

Let's say you have a data set that looks like this:

```
          Vietnam    Gulf War     Iraq War
veteran1    1           0            0
veteran2    0           1            0
veteran3    0           0            1
veteran4    0           1            1  # <---- Note this row
```

You want to consolidate these columns ***without affecting other columns in the dataframe*** like so:

```
          Service  
veteran1    1                  
veteran2    2                     
veteran3    3                            
veteran4    2  # <---- Note this row
```

Where

- `1 = Vietnam`, `2 = Gulf War`, `3 = Iraq War`
- If a veteran has served 2 or more it should pick only one (as is the case with `veteran4` where it picked their left-most column)
- there are many other columns in the dataframe, and they shouldn't be affected by any of this

Questions:

**How would you do this in `R`?**

(Note: if it's easier to do in some other free open source program, please feel free to share which program and how you would do it. This is a massive dataset: 3 million rows, the *American Community Survey*.)

Comment: Something like `data.frame(Service = max.col(df>0, "first"), row.names = row.names(df))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your data, it seems a simple issue of:

if Vietnam > 0, then use 1, otherwise if Gulf war > 0 then 2, otherwise if Iraq > 0 then 3, else 0

```
vietnam = c(1, 0, 0,0) 
gulfwar = c(0,1,0,1)
iraq = c(0,0,1,1)
df = data.frame(vietnam, gulfwar, iraq) 
df$service <- ifelse(df$vietnam > 0,1,ifelse(df$gulfwar>0,2,ifelse(df$iraq>0,3,0)))
df
```

Result:

```
       vietnam gulfwar iraq service
  1       1       0    0       1
  2       0       1    0       2
  3       0       0    1       3
  4       0       1    1       2
```

Comment: Such a simple solution, and I was overthinking it to the point I explored using `tidyr` and `reshape2` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit complicated (respect to other solutions), but here is one approach using `apply`:

```
df$service <-  apply(df, 1, function(x) which(x == 1)[1] )
df
  vietnam gulfwar iraq service
1       1       0    0       1
2       0       1    0       2
3       0       0    1       3
4       0       1    1       2
```